# Why some content doesn't appear browsing with Safari?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari, buddypress

visiting this page ( http://www.legrandclub.net/members ) with Safari (so also visiting it on iPhone) the list of social network members doesn't appear, why?

I can't realize what's the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `display:none` on your members-directory-form `<form>`.

You have attempted to nest `<form>` elements, which is not valid in (X)HTML (See [Element Prohibitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)) and will not succeed when your page is served with the `text/html` content type.

Safari's parser is using a different 'repair' procedure to the other browsers, such that the network members list is inside the members-directory-form in Safari, but not in the other browsers. Hence the `display:none` is only being applied to the list in Safari.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Unfortunately I'm using a default Buddypress template and it's a bit hard to change it, I could try to explicitely set display property to block.

I wil report the solution on this thread.

Comment: Solved as I said in the previous comment.